# how to filter according location in freebase?

Tags: google-api, freebase

i have been trying to filter the suggestions according to location but unsuccessful.
i want to show all locations, city , town,  villages of country : India

what changes should i do to the below code for it ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myinput")
  .suggest({
    "key": "my key",
  filter: '(any type:/location/location )'

  })
 .bind("fb-select", function(e, data) {
   alert(data.name + ", " + data.id + " (" + data['n:type'].name + ")");
});
      </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this with a search filter is to use the `part_of` [Metaschema predicate](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-cookbook#metaschema-constraints) like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myinput")
  .suggest({
    "key": "my key",
  filter: '(all type:/location/location part_of:/m/03rk0)'

  })
 .bind("fb-select", function(e, data) {
   alert(data.name + ", " + data.id + " (" + data['n:type'].name + ")");
});
</script>
```

The `part_of` Metaschema predicate is transitive which means that it matches Freebase topics that are `part_of` India (/m/03rk0) or `part_of` a location which is `part_of` India, etc.

Comment: actually after applying part_of it is not showing the local area names example "vasant kunj" but it is showing without part_of .... how to make this part available in suggestion (example "vasant kunj or vasant vihar") ?

Comment: That's because there were no property values in Freebase to say that Vasant Kunj is part of India. I've just added a /location/location/containedby property that says that Vasant Kunj is part of South West Delhi (/m/027drhq). There were already facts saying the South West Delhi is contained by Delhi and Delhi is contained by India so now the path is complete. Try your code again in an hour and the search index should be updated by then. If you find other missing relationships feel free to add them to Freebase.

Comment: actually i want to make a suggestion list of these areas (thousands) of India (Delhi will also work for now) but they are missing. is there any way or above mentioned by Tom Morris or using "notable type: /location/citytown" or any other to get all these areas in the suggestion list (City+Village+Town+Areas) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Any approach that you take will be limited by the amount of data that has been added to Freebase. The filter that I gave requires the containedby properties to be in place and Tom's answer requires the locations to have geocoordinates. The only way to increase the coverage is to add the missing data.

Comment: how to exclude a continent from search suggestions in selecting locations so that i can use locations to get all location and exclude all continents and countries of asia EXCEPT India ?

Answer (score 1):

Shawn's approach will work for topics which have the containment properties set up correctly, but I'm not sure how good the coverage is there.  I suspect simple geo data (lat/lon) coverage is better. If you want to just filter on distance from the centroid of India, you could do something like:

```
filter=(all type:/location/location (within radius:500km+lon:82.7948 lat:21.7866))
```

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?indent=true&filter=%28all+type%3A/location/location+%28within+radius%3A500km+lon%3A82.7948+lat%3A21.7866%29%29&output=%28geocode%29

Note that this is very sketchily documented and I'm not sure whether that means it's brand new and the documentation isn't finished or deprecated and about to go away.